# Md Access: User defined function value is not showing in Textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my form I have a textbox, `TextBox1` and I have set the control source of the textbox to a user defined function as `=UserTracking()`. UserTracking function is defined in a module named `User_Defined_Functions`. the function is as follow

```
Function UserTracking() As String
Dim test As String
test = "TEST"
End Function
```

Now I am expecting that this `TEST` should appear in the textbox of the form view but it is not showing. It is not giving any error also. How can I make this work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a value to `UserTracking` within the function.

```
Function UserTracking() As String
Dim test As String
test = "TEST"
UserTracking = test
End Function
```